# Is it true $\underset{x\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\vartheta_3\left(0,e^{-\frac{\pi}{x^2}}\right)-x\right)=0$?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-functions

Figure (1) below illustrates the Jacobi theta function $\vartheta_3\left(0,e^{-\frac{\pi}{x^2}}\right)$ and the linear function $x$ in orange and blue respectively.

---

[image]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of $\vartheta_3\left(0,e^{-\frac{\pi}{x^2}}\right)$ (orange) and linear function $x$ (blue)

---

**Question**: Has it been proven (or can it be) than $\underset{x\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\vartheta_3\left(0,e^{-\frac{\pi}{x^2}}\right)-x\right)=0$?

Comment: Why did you tag ```Number theory```
?

Comment: One idea might be to notice that $$\vartheta_3\left(0, e^{- \frac{\pi}{x^2}}\right) = 2 \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} e^{- \pi \frac{k^2}{x^2}} - 1.$$

Comment: @ViktorGlombik I tagged Number Theory because this question is related to a formula for the Riemann Xi function $\xi(s)$ (see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3331469).

Answer (score 1):

It is a very good exercice to **prove** the Fourier series $$f(t)=\sum_n e^{-\pi (t+n)^2 x} = \sum_k x^{-1/2} e^{-\pi k^2/x} e^{2i \pi kt}, \qquad x^{-1/2} e^{-\pi k^2/x}  = \int_0^1 f(t) e^{-2i \pi kt}dt$$ from which it follows that $\lim_{x \to \infty}x-\sum_n e^{-\pi n^2 /x^2} = \lim_{x \to \infty} x-x \sum_n e^{-\pi n^2 x^2} = 0$

and that $\lambda(s) = \pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(s/2)\zeta(s)= \lambda(1-s)$