# Question related to formula for Riemann Xi function $\xi(s)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, riemann-zeta

This question is related to the following formula for the Riemann Xi function $\xi(s)$ which I believe converges for $\Re(s)>0$ (see the two figures following the question below).

**(1)** $\,\xi(s)=X^{-s}\left(\frac{1}{2}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^N\left(e^{-\frac{\pi\,n^2}{X^2}}+\frac{\pi\,n^2\,(s-1)\,E_{-\frac{s}{2}}\left(\frac{n^2\,\pi}{X^2}\right)}{X^2}\right)\right),\,\Re(s)>0\land X\to\infty\land N\gg X$

---

Note the sum over $n$ in formula (1) above can be partially simplified as illustrated in formula (2) below where I believe $\underset{X\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\vartheta_3\left(0,e^{-\frac{\pi}{X^2}}\right)=X$ (see [my related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3331405)).

**(2)** $\quad\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{\pi\,n^2}{X^2}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\vartheta_3\left(0,e^{-\frac{\pi}{X^2}}\right)-1\right)$

---

> **Question**: Is there a closed form for the following expression (which is also related to the sum over $n$ in formula (1) above) for $0<\Re(s)$, $0<\Re(s)<1$, or even just $\Re(s)=\frac{1}{2}$?

**(3)** $\quad\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\,n^2\,E_{-\frac{s}{2}}\left(\frac{n^2\,\pi}{X^2}\right)$

---

The following two figures illustrate formula (1) above for $\xi(s)$ in orange overlaid on the reference function $\xi(s)$ in blue where formula (1) is evaluated at $X=200$ and $N=1000$ in both figures.

---

[image: Illustration of Formula (1) for xi(s)]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of Formula (1) for $\xi(s)$

---

[image: Illustration of Formula (1) for xi(1/2+it)]

**Figure (2)**: Illustration of Formula (1) for $\xi(1/2+i\,t)$

Comment: In (1) if you mean a limit then write $\xi(s ) =\lim_{X \to \infty} ...$. Then do you read the answers to your questions ? I already told you 10 times to not use those $E_s(z)$ things. Use its integral definition whose series over $n$ simplifies immediately.

Comment: @reuns I don't recall you ever directing me with respect to using $E_x(z)$ . Can you give me a reference to a single example? With respect to $X\to\infty\land N\gg X$ I meant what I said. $X\to\infty\land N\to\infty$ is not the same thing. $X\to\infty\land N\gg X$ implies $N\to\infty$, but it also implies more.